# $\pi_0(SO(N))$ and $\pi_0(O(N))$: Inconsistency between Bott periodicity and basic understanding of $\pi_0$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

I need to know the homotopy groups of the oriented Grassmannian $\widetilde{Gr}(\infty,\infty) \cong \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} SO(2N)/(SO(N) \times SO(N))$, and I've run into an inconsistency. It seems that the problem eventually reduces to finding the homotopy groups of the stable special orthogonal group $SO$. One can do this by exploiting Bott periodicity. I haven't found much about Bott periodicity specifically for $SO(N)$, but it's easy to find for $O(N)$: $$\pi_k(O(N)) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}_2 & k = 0,1 \mod 8 \\ \mathbb{Z} & k = 3,7 \mod 8 \\ 0 & k = 2,4,5,6 \mod 8 \end{cases}$$ Since $\pi_k(SO(N)) = \pi_k(O(N))$, this gives us all the homotopy groups for $SO$.

The problem is that this tells us that for sufficiently high $N$ (i.e., $N \ge k+2$), $\pi_0(SO(N)) = \pi_0(O(N)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$. $\pi_0$ counts the path-connected components of a space, and while $O(N)$ does indeed have two of them, $SO(N)$ has only one, so $\pi_0(SO(N))$ should be $0$, not $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Therefore, something is wrong with the result from Bott periodicity.

Which of these arguments is wrong, and why?

Comment: I think bott periodicity applies to $O=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty O(n)$? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Homotopy_groups,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem ?

Comment: @snulty Yes, it applies to $O$, but for any $\pi_k$, it also applies for sufficiently large $N$. The uniqueness of $O$ is that it applies for all $\pi_k$ in that case, since $O$ is effectively $O(\infty)$. (As far as I know, potentially with some exceptions for small $k$, e.g. 0, which may be part of my misunderstanding here.)

Comment: Ah alright thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality $\pi_kSO(n)=\pi_kO(n)$ is only true for $k>0$.

In fact $SO(n)$ is one of the two connected components of $O(n)$, so $\pi_0SO(n)=0$.

Comment: Great! So then, which is true: $\pi_8(SO) = \pi_0(SO)$, or $\pi_8(SO)=\pi_8(O)$? Does Bott periodicity not apply to $\pi_0$? (Something I've read makes me think maybe it only applies for $\pi_k$ when $k \ge 2$.)

Comment: Yes, Bott periodicity for SO holds only for $k>0$. In fact, it is for $k>0$ an immediate consequence of Bott periodicity for $O$ because obviously $\pi_kSO=\pi_kO$ for $k>0$.